# How to get access to kubernetes cluster from containerized application running inside node hosted on same cluster?

Tags: c#, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-cluster

I am using kubernetes client library for c#. This method should ideally provide me with k8s config of the cluster it is running inside

`var k8sConfig = KubernetesClientConfiguration.InClusterConfig();`

Inside docker container when this run it gives

`k8s.Autorest.HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'`

Expected behaviour is to get cluster inside application so as to use its configmaps and secrets.
Is there any other method to do this or are there any pre-requisites to use this method?

Please note: I am using token login from web UI for cluster dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/discussions/891

I asked over github too, which was answered by moderators. And this is what we need to do here. Keep "clusterrolbinding" concept in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the configmap values you can mount it to your pod as shown here.(same for secret)
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/
Then these would be available to your pod as env variables.

Comment: No, we dont want to mount it as they have vulnerable info and we dont want to pass them as env variables

Comment: if someone has access to the env variables in your pod then they would also have access to the configmaps you don't want to mount.

Comment: Well its not a very ethical practice, thats why we want to get config inside our container and use client library methods to fetch configmaps